# How do I extract variables from a list in fish?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, fish

So, I recently downloaded a cli which shares a lot of commands similar to linux.
Like `mega-login` : `login` & `mega-logout` :`logout`
and I am too tired of writing mega every time I need to use the cli.
I thought of using alias but I don't want to screw some other program that use the some other command I don't know of.
Like if I create an alias `login` then what will happen to the system `login` command? Plus there are a lot of commands in the cli.

So, I thought of using a script, but I didn't know how to do it.
Here what I had in my mind.
So when I use `m login` or `m logout` it will search if a command `mega-login` or `mega-logout` exists and then call it.

So I tried hours coming up with various functions while learning fish and this is what I wrote.

```
function m --argument value $argv
    echo value $value $argv
    if type mega-$value
        set MEGA
        for temp in $argv
            set MEGA $MEGA$temp
            echo $MEGA
        end
        echo MEGA \n\n $MEGA
        eval $MEGA
    end
end
```

This still doesn't work.
PS: I wrote this on my first try, but I dropped it once I couldn't figure it out.

```
function m --argument value $argv
    echo value $value $argv
    if type mega-$value
        set MEGA mega-$argv
        echo $argv \n\n\n $MEGA
    eval $MEGA
    end
end
```

Comment: I removed the "SOLVED" tagging of the title of the question. Accepting an answer is enough to mark a question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bad first (and second) attempt.  It can be tricky to get it just right.

How about:

```
function m
    set -l mega_cmd "mega-$argv[1]"
    set -l mega_args $argv[2..]
    if type -q "$mega_cmd"
        echo "Executing $mega_cmd $mega_args"
        "$mega_cmd" $mega_args
    end
end
```

Of course, that's for readability (which I prefer), but it can be condensed down to:

```
function m
    if type -q "mega-$argv[1]"
        echo "Executing mega-$argv[1] $argv[2..]"
        "mega-$argv[1]" $argv[2..]
    end
end
```

Comment: Random thoughts for improvements -- If you really want to keep the "Executing ..." in there, probably better to send it to stderr so as to not pollute any output results from your actual `mega-x` commands.  Also, of course, would be good to have an `else` block to provide an error message if the `mega-x` command isn't found.

Comment: It helped me a lot, I was going to abbr every command if I couldn't find any way.

Comment: Great to hear that helped. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer. And check back, because someone else may have an even better solution.  And if that happens, I want you to have the opportunity to accept theirs instead! Thanks!

Comment: This will fail if only a function of that name exists. `type -q` checks for all kinds of callable things - functions, builtins and commands. And then you attempt to just run an external command with `command`. My preference would be to just remove the `command` entirely. (also most of the quoting here is superfluous)

Comment: Thanks @faho All good points.  I removed `command` from the function.  Any idea why the commandline editor then flags the `"$mega_cmd"` (quoted or unquoted, it doesn't matter) as an error?  It still *works*; just that it is highlighted in red in the editor.  Also, I realized that quoting the command variable was overkill, but I'm just trying to maintain "good variable quoting" habits.  It would take a pathologic command (with a space in the command itself) to break the unquoted version, I know.  There's no potential *harm* in leaving it quoted, though, right?

Comment: No, a space in the command itself would not be an issue. Fish does not perform word splitting.

Comment: And the reason the commandline flags it as an error is most likely because the variable isn't defined yet - it doesn't do a full static analysis of which variables could be set, and flags attempts to use unset or empty variables as commands as an error.

Comment: To be clear: If you `set foo "something with spaces"`, you can then use `$foo` anywhere, without quotes, and it will be used as one element, with the space intact. This is a change from POSIX-shells which would split it into pieces. A simple way to think about it is that fish keeps elements as they are set.